# Vue.js: How to encapsulate a external/embedded Widget

Tags: javascript, vue.js, widget, embed, vite

I'm trying to build a embeddable widget with Vue 3 & Vite.
I'm trying to achieve this with vue's defineCustomElement feature.

Here a example of the the `widget.js` file:

```
import { createApp, defineCustomElement } from "vue";
import Widget from "./components/Widget.ce.vue";

const TestWidget = defineCustomElement(Widget);
customElements.define("test-widget", TestWidget);
```

Here a example of the the `vite.config.js` file:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                widget: "resources/js/widget.js",
            },
            output: {
                entryFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
                chunkFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
                assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`,
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Now I have to include the `widget.js` file in an other website and add the `<test-widget />` to the body of the page. It works fine, but when the website includes also a build of Vue, I'm getting many js errors.

Is it possible to encapsulate the embedded Vue build?

Answer (score 0):

You can render a simple `<iframe>` element with Vue, using `about:blank` as the `src` to inherit the parent origin (so it will be possible to access the iframe contents from the parent), then render the entire app as a slot withing the iframe, This will encapsulate your app from the parent website.

[This blog post](https://medium.com/@ryanseddon/rendering-to-iframes-in-react-d1cb92274f86)  demonstrates an example how to achieve the mentioned approach using React but it can easily be implemented with Vue as well, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rzuno6kv/.) for a Vue 2 example.